# SMTP Relay server for sending emails in python

Tags: python-3.x, email

I have a requirement where I need to send emails from my python code to more than 400 recipients at a time. The relay server in my organization has a restriction where I can only send email to 20 recipients in an hour. This relay server looks like this: `abcd12.org.com`

There's another relay server which doesn't have this 20 recipients restriction which we used previously in an application build in R. This relay looks like: `23a24a97-10ee-9gc7-923g-b3ebc1f7a385@org.com`

Problem is I can't figure out a way to use the second server in my python code since this relay looks like an email address whereas the first one looks like a server address. I get below error in python if I use the second relay server.

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

How can I use relay server that looks like the email address in my python code?

This is my function to send out email out.

```
def send_email_with_attachments(sender, recipient, cc_recipient, subject, body, attachments):

    commaspace = ', '
    file_paths = attachments

    # Create the enclosing (outer) message
    outer = MIMEMultipart()
    outer['Subject'] = subject
    outer['To'] = commaspace.join(recipient)
    outer['From'] = sender
    outer['Cc'] = commaspace.join(cc_recipient)
    outer.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'
    outer.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    for filename in file_paths:
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            continue
        # Guess the content type based on the file's extension.  Encoding
        # will be ignored, although we should check for simple things like
        # gzip'd or compressed files.
        ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
        if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
            # No guess could be made, or the file is encoded (compressed), so
            # use a generic bag-of-bits type.
            ctype = 'application/octet-stream'
        maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
        if maintype == 'text':
            fp = open(filename)
            # Note: we should handle calculating the charset
            msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
            fp.close()
        elif maintype == 'image':
            fp = open(filename, 'rb')
            msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
            fp.close()
        elif maintype == 'audio':
            fp = open(filename, 'rb')
            msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
            fp.close()
        else:
            fp = open(filename, 'rb')
            msg = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
            msg.set_payload(fp.read())
            fp.close()
            # Encode the payload using Base64
            encoders.encode_base64(msg)
        # Set the filename parameter
        filename = os.path.basename(filename)
        msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
        outer.attach(msg)
    # Now send or store the message
    composed = outer.as_string()
    
    s = smtplib.SMTP('23a24a97-10ee-9gc7-923g-b3ebc1f7a385@org.com', port=123)
    s.sendmail(sender, recipient, composed)
    s.quit()
```

Comment: The name with the @ sign is not valid for a host, see [RFC 1035](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-2.3.1). You need to fix the host name before you can connect with anything. This is not email-specific. Or change the configuration of the other mail relay. 20/h seems way too low.